# I was trying to create randomly positioned objects that should not collide. My collider does not seem to detect properly. How do I fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

I have a prefab empty object that contains the rotating cube. I was trying to do the technique here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/356438/how-to-stop-a-collider-rotating-with-the-gameobjec.html  . I have a proper tag, the onTrigger checkbox is checked.

**FoodGenerator**

```
public class FoodGenerator : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject food;

public int foodCount;
void Start () {
    for (int i = 0; i < foodCount; i++){
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-8.0f, 8.0f), 1.0f, Random.Range(-8.0f, 8.0f));
        Instantiate(food, position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

}

**NonRotatingCollider**

```
public class NonRotatingCollider : MonoBehaviour {
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Triggered", other);
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pick Up"))
        {
            Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-8.0f, 8.0f), 1.0f, Random.Range(-8.0f, 8.0f));
            transform.position = position;
        }
    }
}
```

The Debug.Log("Triggered") here does not even activate. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `OnTriggerEnter` function to be called, the `isTrigger` property must be enabled on the collider. Also, a Rigidbody must be attached to the collider. There is no evidence you've attached Rigidbody to the GameObject. If Rigidbody is already attached this GaeObject, make sure that isKinematic is *not* enabled on both colliding Rigidbodies.

OnTriggerEnter should be called when none or just one of the colliding Rigidbody has isKinematic enabled. If both colliding Rigidbody has isKinematic enabled, OnTriggerEnter  will not be called.